# Chart Js , Overlap y Stack en Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Es posible graficar de la siguiente manera?

- Dos barras
- La otra "Overlap" es decir, superpuestas.
- Una de ellas "Stacked" es decir, sumando ambas.

**Ex:**
[image: Ex]

Actualmente ambas se stackean,Data 4 y Data 2 se suman.

**Actual:**
[image: Test]

**Esperado: Lo esperado es que Data 4 y Data 2 se superpongan**
[image: Ex]

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1"],
  datasets: [
    
     {
      stack:2,
      label: "Data 4",
      backgroundColor: "grey",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100],
    },
    {
      stack:2,
      label: "Data 2",
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [80],

    },
    {
      stack:1,
      label: "Data 3",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [50],

    },
      {
      stack:1,
      label: "Data 1",
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [20],
    },
   
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿puedes explicar un poco mejor tu pregunta? ¿solo necesita una overlap?

Comment: @Ivandez Tal y como mostré en la pregunta, son 2 barras.  Una hace overlap una con otra, (Es decir, se superponen no se stackean)  y la otra barra stackea los 2 valores.
Por ejemplo, Barra 1 (overlaped) tiene 2 valores, 80 y 100. sin sumarse.
Barra 2, 50 y 20. Sumandose llegando a 70 en la escala de x.

Answer (score 4):

Actualmente no es posible fijar esta opcion individualmente.  Talvez la mejor forma de presentar los datos seria usando una barra superpuesta y las otras separadas.  Algo asi:

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1"],
  datasets: [    
     
    {
      stack:2,
      label: "Data 2",
      backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [80],

    },
    {
      stack:2,
      label: "Data 4",
      backgroundColor: "grey",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100],
    },    
      {
      
      label: "Data 1",
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [20],      
      stacked: true
    },
    {
      
      label: "Data 3",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [50],
      stacked: true
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
  scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: false,
      },
      y: {
        stacked: false
      }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Se podría hacer 2 stacked( [Verde / Gris] [Amarillo / Azul ] ) y en la gris restarle la verde claro? es decir que la verde este en 80 y la gris en 20 y al poner el mouse encima que marque el total y el restante?